# Blender molecular addon to create full object

Tags: physics

When using the molecular addon i was thinking about how these molecules could be rendered in different ways. Firstly, each molecule as a ball, this is how it is normally done, but i want to find out how to do it another way.

Is there a way of using all the outside molecules as vertices of a object and creating a solid object using these. This could be done by making faces between the outside molecules of the object.

Is this possible and how would i accomplish this?

Comment: CubeSurfer add-on from the same developer. It's a mesher for particles.

Comment: Hey, LukeD, this seems as a valid solution! Why not expand to a full answer? Thanks.